# search multiple columns for a value and concatenate the address of the cells

Tags: excel

I have been breaking my head over this formula for sometime now. I have found a solution which is too big and not so convenient to use every time. So can any Excel Expert give me a solution/suggestion?

Column A contains 150 values. Column D to R contains a table in which I need to look up the values in A one by one. I want to return address of all the cells that contains the value.

For example, Value in `A2` is present in cells `D5`, `E15`, `H10`, `R3` then my result should be `D5,E15,H10,R13`.

Please Note that some columns may not contain the value of `A2`, I do not want them displayed.

Here is the formula I have written:

```
=CONCATENATE(
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(D:D,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,D:D,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,D:D,0),4,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(E:E,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,E:E,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,E:E,0),5,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(F:F,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,F:F,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,F:F,0),6,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(G:G,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,G:G,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,G:G,0),7,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(H:H,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,H:H,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,H:H,0),8,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(I:I,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,I:I,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,I:I,0),9,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(J:J,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,J:J,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,J:J,0),10,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(K:K,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,K:K,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,K:K,0),11,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(L:L,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,L:L,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,L:L,0),12,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(M:M,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,M:M,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,M:M,0),13,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(N:N,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,N:N,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,N:N,0),14,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(O:O,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,O:O,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,O:O,0),15,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(P:P,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,P:P,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,P:P,0),16,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(Q:Q,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,Q:Q,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,Q:Q,0),17,4),0),",",
IF(A2=IF(COUNTIF(R:R,A2),VLOOKUP(A2,R:R,1,FALSE),""),ADDRESS(MATCH(A2,R:R,0),18,4),0))
```

As I said, this works but I am looking for a simpler and smaller formula.

Hint: Maybe using array can help?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You've got yourself confused. `A` is a column, not a row. `D5` is a cell, not a column. Also, monstrous formula.

Comment: Sorry, Its column A which contains 150 values. D5 is a cell. Thanks!

Comment: Consider a custom function using VBA.  Much easier for iterating through values.

Comment: Your existing formula looks like it's only going to return the *first* matching address from each column of your table. Is that what you want, or do you want *all* values from each column? (Or are values within a given column always unique?)

Comment: Your assumption is right. Values within a given column are always unique. So it returns the first matching address from each column.  I cannot use VBA :(

Comment: I'm trying to ask if the values in the columns are all different from each other, or can there be repeats?

Comment: No repeats within a column. They have unique value and only those values that are present in Column A

Comment: Okay, good. Just to clarify, no repeats in column A *and* no repeats in columns D through R?

Comment: Column A has no repeats, all unique values. Column d has no repeats  too but values are subset of values in Column A. Same is the case with all other columns E,F,....,R.    So Column D(Cell D5) may contain same value as Column M (Cell M10). We have to find those and concatenate the address of these cells. Hope this is clear !!

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to accomplish is not a great fit for Excel formulas, but it can be done with a smaller, simpler formula dragged across 15 columns instead of 1 giant complicated formula that tries to do everything at once.

Assuming column A has 150 values (from A1 to A150), and there is a table going from D1 to R50...

1. Enter `=S1&IFERROR(","&ADDRESS(MATCH($A1,D$1:D$50,0),COLUMN(D1)),"")` into T1.
2. Drag the formula across to AH1.
3. Enter `=RIGHT(AH1,LEN(AH1)-1)` into AI1.
4. Select T1 to AI150 and press Ctrl-D.

Column AI1 will contain the results you are looking for.

How does this work?

- The formula in T1 begins by taking the result of one cell to the left (which is blank). Then it concatenates this with the address of the first match in column D (prefixed by a comma). If there is no match, it just concatenates blank (""). As you drag this formula to the right, it keeps concatenating addresses as matches come up (or blank if there are none). When you get to the end, you will have looked for matches in all 15 column of your table.
- The formula in AI1 just strips off the initial comma if there is one.

Comment: Thanks! I understand this is a simple formula but my concern is, I have pulled huge data from database which are spread over several columns. So wanted to bring the result directly in one cell. Is this in scope in Excel?

Comment: It can be done in Excel, but as @Richard Vivian said, you probably need to resort to writing a VBA formula.

Comment: Ok. As I am not aware of VBA, it would be difficult for me to proceed with this. Thanks.